# How to remove in a doubly linked list - Python?

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

I would like to make a doubly linked list in Python. However the rem = remove is giving me problems. I can remove the first element, but I can not remove an element in the middle or in the end.

class Node:

```
def __init__(self, value):  
    self.data = value  
    self.next = None  
    self.prev = None
```

class ListDL:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__head = None  
    self.__tail = None  
    self.__size = 0  

def rem(self, item):
    if self.__head is None:
        print("The list is empty")
        return
    if self.__head.next is None:
        if self.__head.data == item:
            self.__head = None
        else:
            print("Item not found")
        return

    if self.__head.data == item:
        self.__head = self.__head.next
        self.__head.prev = None
        return

    n = self.__head
    while n.next is not None:
        if n.data == item:
            break
        n = n.next
    if n.next is not None:
        n.prev.next = n.next
        n.next.prev = n.prev
    else:
        if n.data == item:
            n.prev.next = None
        else:
            print("Item is not present")
```

Comment: Please add the driver code that creates the list, calls `rem` and demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two issues in your `rem` method:

- It never updates `self.__tail`. It should do so when the tail node is the one that has the data to remove.
- It only deletes the *first* node that has the value. If it is intended that *all* nodes should be removed that have that value, then you need to continue iteration through your list in order to find other occurrences.

Here is how you could write it:

```
    def rem(self, item):
        n = self.__head
        while n is not None:
            nxt = n.next
            if n.data == item:
                if n.prev:
                    n.prev.next = n.next
                else:
                    self.__head= n.next
                if n.next:
                    n.next.prev = n.prev
                else:
                    self.__tail = n.prev
            n = nxt
```